# Multiple Textbox values into database

Tags: asp.net, c#-2.0

I have multiple textboxes in my form like txtTask0, txtTask1... txtTask12.

so I want to pass values of those textboxes into my webservice one by one.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 12 ; i++)
{
   sOUT = ws_service.InsertAchievement(i,txtTask0.Text,txtAchieve0.Text);              
}
```

Here instead of passing txtTask0.text I need to pass the "i" value one by one like

```
txtTask[i].text
```

something similar to this

```
TextBox tb = (TextBox) Controls["txtTask" + i];
```

from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022724/textbox-values-to-array)
But that code results in error like

```
Error   92  The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.UI.ControlCollection.this[int]' has some invalid arguments
```

How can I pass multiple textbox values into the loop.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant do like that, because the Controls[index] expects an integer as its parameter, but you are passing a "string concatenated with an integer" it wont work, instead you do like below it will work, hope it will help you...

```
            foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
            {
                int i = 0;
                if (c is TextBox)
                {
                    while(i < 10)
                    {
                        if (c.Name == "txtTask" + i)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("This is textBox" + i);
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
```

EDIT :

If the condition `if(c is TextBox)` is not parsing correctly then do like

```
           foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
            {
                int i = 0;
                while (i < this.Controls.Count)
                {
                    if (c.Name == "txtTask" + i)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("This is textBox" + i);
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            }
```

EDIT 2:

Or Simply if you want to loop out in all textbox controls in aspx page use this following code part. It works very perfectly..

```
        int count = 0;
        foreach (Control c in this.Page.Controls)
        {
            foreach (Control c1 in c.Controls)
            {
                int i = 0;
                if (c1 is TextBox)
                {
                    while (i < 10)
                    {
                        if (c1.ID == "TextBox" + i)
                        {
                            count++;
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Label1.Text = count + " textbox(es) has been found";
```

Comment: Sorry. The above code not passing `if (c is TextBox)` statement And how to get the value of textbox here. Because c.Name property is not found. I tried with c.ID.

Comment: `Control c` holds controls like `LiteralControl`, `HtmlForm` etc., It is not holding `TextBox` control. Am I missing something?

Comment: if the textbox controls are not there in your project, compare only with name of control. Comment the `if(c is TextBox)` line and test again.

Comment: I have many TextBox controls in my form. But the code not at all reading any controls other than LiteralControl and HtmlForm.

Comment: `String txtOption;
            TextBox txtTask = new TextBox();
  for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
            {


                txtOption = "txtTask" + i;

                txtTask.Text = ((TextBox)FindControl(txtOption)).Text;

                Response.Write(txtTask.Text);
}`
I tried this code. It is working. 
And your code still not entering into `if` statement because the loop not finding TextBox control. I dont know where the problem is.
Thanks for your instant help.

Comment: I had given you an another code part in my "Edit", have you tried it?

Comment: yeah I tried that. For that code only I replied. Am working on aspx code but your code similar to windows application. Is that a problem?

Comment: @itzArun, now refer to the last edited code. There you are it works simply fine...

Comment: But if am using that code, the loop `if (c1 is TextBox)` says no TextBox controls in the page.